# Compress a vector using simplified version of RLE in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array made of 0 and 1. I want to compress it using RLE method. For example:
If input is 00001110001001, I want the function to return 433121, assuming the 1D array starts with a sequence of 0.

I'm new to numpy and know only a few commands. I tried to solve the problem using for loop but it was slow. What is the numpy way to solve this?

Comment: Can you post your loop-based solution? It'll be easier to translate that into numpy than starting from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by calculating the indices where there is a change in value by subtracting adjacent values and the [nonzero](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.nonzero.html#numpy.ndarray.nonzero) method. The difference between consecutive indices is then the length of the run:

```
import numpy as np

def compress(array):
    # Put a different value at start and end of array: [0, 1, 1] -> [1, 0, 1, 1, 0] etc ...
    array = np.array([1 ^ array[0], *array, 1 ^ array[-1]])
    change = (array[1:]-array[:-1]).nonzero()[0]
    return change[1:] - change[:-1]
```

Test and time:

```
assert (compress(np.array([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1])) == np.array([4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1])).all()

rng = np.random.default_rng()

data = rng.integers(0, 2, 1000)

%timeit compress(data)
```

Output:

```
73.1 µs ± 79.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

This can also be combined with [numba](https://numba.pydata.org) to make it approximately 10 times faster:

```
import numba as nb
compress2 = nb.njit(compress)
compress2(data)
%timeit compress2(data)
```

Output

```
7.51 µs ± 70.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```